# Passing an object to redirect()

Tags: django

I need to pass an object to redirect function. Is this the way to go about it ?

```
redirect('/view', kwargs={'obj': obj})
```

`def view(request, obj):
    do something`

How do I implement it so url dispatcher accepts it ? I would use:

`url(r'view/.+', view, name='whatever'),`

Since I'm passing an object I'm not using url converters (str, int, slug, etc) but using regular expression that tells url dispatcher to accept anything I pass to it, however this is throwing me an error.

What is the right way to go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I implement it so url dispatcher accepts it?

**You *can* not do that**. you can not pass an object itself through a URL (or through anything else), or at least not without using a lot of "hacks", by using a serializer like `pickle`, but that would generate huge URLs (URLs are not strictly limited, but usually it is advisable to keep a URL shorter than 2000 characters). An empty dictionary will already take 8 characters if you encode it with a base64 encoding over a pickle stream.

You can not pass a generic object to a URL. You can only pass text as the URL. You can convert an integer to text, etc. But converting a generic object to text, that strictly speaking *can* be done (through pickling), but that is not recommended at all. It would furthermore potentially expose the webserver internals. If for example your object somehow refers to the Django settings, it might encode the database credentials, and thus impose a severe security risk.

You thus can pass text, or convert some data to text. In order to handle that, you first need to define a parameter in your `url`. How else will you capture the data. We can thus define a parameter, like:

```
url(r'view/(?P<obj>.*)/$', view, name='whatever'),
```

You can then generate a redirect by using the *name* of the view, and passing the parameters as named parameters:

```
redirect('whatever', obj='sometext')
```

Then the `view` will be called with `obj` as `'sometext'`. Usually one passes the primary key, slug, etc. This makes it easy to read, compact, and furthermore it only exposes a small amount of data to the client.